# Search a data in table using datepicker in extjs

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2

I created a table where I need to sort the values using the dates, so I used the **datepicker** but its not working how to sort the data using the date picker.
 The exact output is if i select the date **"17-09-01"** I need to get the columns which have these dates.
once if i given some date on textbox, based on textbox value I need to filter related records from all columns. Can you tell me how to achieve? 
What change I need to do?
You can view my code in [Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/27qc)

Comment: Where are the dates in that fiddle?

Comment: @Alexander sorry sir..now you check my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made following changes to your code to make it work.

1. In a model, specify the `date` field properly with `dateFormat`.

   ```
                   {
                       name: 'date',
                       type: 'date',
                       dateFormat: 'y-m-d'
                   }
   ```
2. In a grid, better use `datecolumn` with `format` property.

   ```
            {
               //Use xtype datecolumn for dates and specify the format
               xtype: 'datecolumn',
               text: 'Date',
               dataIndex: 'date',
               flex: 2,
               format: 'y-m-d'
           }
   ```
3. Avoid using `storeId` on store, though you had not specified it but were trying to retrieve store by it.

   ```
           handler: function (picker, date) {
             //var store = Ext.getStore('storeId');
             var store = picker.up('#myGridItemId').getStore();
             // clear current filters
             store.clearFilter();
            // filter store
            var date = Ext.first('#selectedDate').getValue();
            store.filter("date", date);
           }
   ```
4. Here's the [modified](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/27tb) code. Read my comments for more.

Answer (score 0):

Try this you can search using date, name and email id

In the Below code u want to add **gridfilters** plugins.

```
 items: [{
        xtype: 'grid',
        title: 'Sample Data',
        itemId: 'myGridItemId',
        flex: 1.2,
        plugins: 'gridfilters',
        margin: '0 10 0 0',
        bind: {
            store: '{mystore}',
            selection: '{users}'
        },
```

> 

```
 columns: [{
             text: 'Name',
            dataIndex: 'name',
             flex: 0.5,
                filter: {
           type: 'string', 
            itemDefaults: {

             }
         }
         }, {
            text: 'Email',
             dataIndex: 'email',
             flex: 1,
                filter: {
             type: 'string',
             itemDefaults: {

             }
        }
               },{
                type: 'Date',
            text: 'Date',
                dataIndex: 'date',
                flex: 2,
                filter: {
             type: 'string', 
             itemDefaults: {

             }
         }
              }]
```

Comment: this works perfect but i want this search filter to work when i click the ok button

Comment: Okay fine i will try to change it

Comment: I want only my datepicker to filter my datas...any way thanks for ur answer this work perfectly